# Show all file extensions for all apps

Tags: macos, monterey

I just migrated from High Sierra to Monterey, and I'm not used to file dialogues not showing the file extension. Setting "show all file extensions" in Finder preferences only sets it for Finder, not for "save as" dialogues for other apps. How can I set "show all file extensions" globally (i.e. for every app)?

Comment: Have you rebooted since?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, many times, and I have also installed a system update (which is irrrelevant). I'm supposed to post this question last week but forget to do so.